# Using TCP outside the LAN

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, tcpclient, serversocket

I'm using the the examples provided by Microsoft to learn how to use TCP servers in C#. For TCPListener I use this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx , and for TCPCLient I use this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx (the examples are at the bottom of the page).

Until now I've managed to connect and send messages to other PCs connected to the same router. What I want now is to connect it to a PC outside my LAN network. How can I do that ?

I should also mention that this is the way that I use to connect PCs in LAN :

on ther server side:

```
    public string LocalIPAddress()
    {
        IPHostEntry host;
        string localIP = "";
        host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
        {
            if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                localIP = ip.ToString();
                break;
            }
        }
        return localIP;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        TcpListener server = null;
        try
        {
            // Set the TcpListener on port 13000.
            Int32 port = 13000;
            String localAddrString = LocalIPAddress();
            Console.WriteLine(localAddrString);

            IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse(localAddrString);

// TcpListener server = new TcpListener(port);
            server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);

            // Start listening for client requests.
            server.Start();
```

}
}

on the client side:

```
            Int32 port = 13000;

            String server = "192.168.X.X"; // here I manually introduce the IP provided     by the server in the console
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient(server, port);
```

Comment: There's no difference.  You just use the address of the host you want to connect to.  As long as that address is routable through the network (intranet, internet, doesn't matter) and the port is open to the destination host, it should work.  Have you tried?

Comment: @David, yes I did, and it didn't work. I used my Ip as it is shown at http://whatismyipaddress.com/ . Using the same PCs in LAN it works, but outside of it, it doesn't.

Comment: Anything between the client and the server can block the connection.  If you're trying to connect from outside a residential connection to inside a residential connection, you'll specifically want to check if the port is open on your router and on the cable/dsl/etc. hardware.

Comment: #David, I see. And how can I check that ? Programmatically preferably?

Comment: Unless your router has an API that you can connect to, it's probably going to be manual configuration.  This really has become less a question about code and more a question about network configuration.

Comment: @David, I'm using the next solution to try to find a free port (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7da7c3bb-4205-4451-bb60-310d64804862/which-port-to-use-for-tcp-listener) but anything I do, my program crushes at server.start() and it's returning me the next error : "The requested address is not valid in its context";

Comment: Are you using the public IP as the server trying to listen, or as the client trying to connect to the server?  As the server, you need to use the internal IP address.  Basically the one known to the network interface.  As the client, you'd use the public address to connect to it.  The router would need to forward the public connection to the internal connection.

Answer (score 1):

I wish I could use a simple comment to give you this information but I cannot due to me only recently joining SO. You should ensure you have port forwarded (http://portforward.com/ will help you port forward), if you don't know how to you could use this easy-to-use port checker: http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/.